# How do I correctly format this string so that it passes the correct data?

Tags: javascript

In a JS popup I have a button defined in a var.

```
var blaa = "12";
//var blaa = "aa";

var button = '<a class="nav-link " data-toggle="modal" onclick="showcontent(199,'+ blaa + ')" href="#">Show content</a>';
```

```
function showcontent(ID, contenttext){
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=contenttext;
..
```

If 'blaa' is a number than everything is fine, but if 'blaa' is text than I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: aa is not defined.

I assume that perhaps it is not possible to pass these with onclick within a var and so I have attempted to do something similar with href, which I did get to work as normal button, but due to the quotes I don't know how to get it to work within a variable.

```
var button = '<a class="nav-link " data-toggle="modal" href="'javascript:showcontent();'";>Show content</a>'; // this doesn't work and I don't know how to format it correctly.
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showcontent('199', 'aa');return false;">Show content</button> //this works fine outside of a variable, but once it's in a variable I can no longer use a string as second parameter.
```

Comment: Of course it is _possible_ - you just need to wrap the string value into proper delimiters. And if they collide with the string context you are already in - then you need to _escape_ them. (But of course it should rather not be _done_ this way any more these days, you should bind your event handlers via JavaScript to begin with, rather than via inline event handler attributes.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ?

```
var blaa = "aa";

var button = `<a class="nav-link " data-toggle="modal" onclick="showcontent(199,'${blaa}')" href="#">Show content</a>`;
```